# Views Module: Display a key from user data (Drupal 7.x-3.11)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I'm having problems wit the *User: Data* field.

I want to set the Display format to *A certain key* to output the identifier value from this serialized data (relevant snippet):

```
a:1:{s:10:"hybridauth";a:26:{s:10:"identifier";s:17:"76561198181833179";
```

When I enter identifier as key, I only get this notice and no output:

> Notice: Undefined index: identifier in
>   views_handler_field_serialized->render() (line 60 of
>   /www/htdocs/****/sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_field_serialized.inc).

What do I have to enter in the "*Which key should be displayed*"-field exactly, to display the identifier value?

Views Module: Display a certain key from the serialized user data (Drupal 7.x-3.11)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to alter your view using hook_views_pre_view.

Steps:

1. Add a uid field and make it hidden in your view.
2. Add a custom or html field to your views(so that you can alter later).
3. In hook_views_pre_view and for the above view and above view display write your php logic to load the current user with the uid field in the view.
4. After loading the user use the data value of the loaded user and unserialize it and replace it with the custom or html field value.

Thanks